# How can I specify the home realm in wpf client?

Tags: wpf, wcf, thinktecture-ident-server

we developed applications with custom STS as identity provider. Now we planning to use  thinktecture identity server (Idsrv) as primary and ADFS as secondary to replace our custom STS. I enabled WS-Federation protocol in Idsrv and added Idsrv and ADFS as identity providers. we developed web application that trusts Idsrv. I also used HRD url to show the list of identity providers whenever user access the web application. It works fine for both identity providers.

Flows :
Idsrv provider      web app-->HRD-->Idsrv-->HRD--->Web app
ADFS                  web app-->HRD-->ADFS-->HRD--->Web app

I also specify the home realm in web application to use the identity provider as default without showing HRD. It works good.

I want to develop a wcf service that trusts Idsrv. I want to utilise the wcf service from wpf client. Based on the user's domain, I need to specify the identity provider as default.
How can I specify the identity provider in wpf client?

my requirement is same as 
https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2/issues/198

Answer (score 0):

The HRD concept does not exist in WCF / SOAP. You would need to go to the idp first and then exchange that token with a token from IdSrv.

Unfortunately, we haven't implemented those endpoint in idsrv. There is a PR on github with an implementation, maybe you wanna give that a try.